# How to Download an html page in a pdf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I have already written some java script code in order to download the html page as to excel which works fine, however i do not know on how to approach the javascript code for the pdf file download.

would appreciate a bit of help thanks in advance

```
  function fnExcelReport() {
    // formatting for the headers
    var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#EE7000'>";
    var textRange;
    var j = 0;
    // grab the table data
    tab = document.getElementById('PrintSummaryTable'); // id of table
    //for each row in the table
    for (j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) {

        tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
    }

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus();
        sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
    }
    else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));

    return (sa);
}

<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();"> EXPORT TO EXCEL </button>
```

Comment: Please post your code if you can, anyway from what I have understood you need this  `<a href="Link_to_your_pdf" download>
  Download
</a>`

Comment: @Ryad code posted

Comment: You  can use jsdf for converting html page to pdf. You can find this library here :  http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/